# Where can I find the gnome applets scripts that I can look at them?

Tags: gnome, panel, applet

How can I see the code of gnome panels? for example view the code is executed When I click on shutdown button in the panel.

Comment: why do you want to view the code? Maybe if you give a better description of what you want to do? :)

Comment: @garbagecollector I am still looking a method to do this. http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/execute-script-before-shutting-down Probably looking the code Shutdown button does, I could insert my app before.

Comment: ahh. did you try superuser.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see it the relevant code is in [`panel-action-button.c`](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-panel/tree/gnome-panel/panel-action-button.c). This code handles the shutdown and other things. You find the complete code at [git repository of gnome-panel](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-panel/).

Comment: I thought it was a shell script instead a binary written in C, Thanks for the link, it is interesting to take a look to gnome source code.